# How to check whether the user is admin or not in Microsoft Teams tab

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have Angular based tab running on Microsoft Teams.

I am interested in how to know the loggined user is admin or not.

So far I am trying to play around with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf?$top=5`. But I believe this requires some permissions and I am not sure how to add one?

Also, Is there any other way to get to know the roles of the user logged in MS Teams app using Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as an "admin of the tenant" but there are roles that grant you admin permissions.

To know if user is an "admin" you need to do two things:

**First** you need to request role list using this request:

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles

> documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

In the response you will see all roles. Let's say you need only Global Admins. Here's an example of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryRoles",
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "9ed3a0c4-53e1-498c-ab4d-2473476fde14",
      "deletedDateTime": null,
      "description": "Can manage all aspects of Azure AD and Microsoft services that use Azure AD identities.",
      "displayName": "Global Administrator"
    },
    ...data is trunkated...
```

**Second** is to retrieve the list of principals that are assigned to the role you are interested in:

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/9ed3a0c4-53e1-498c-ab4d-2473476fde14/members

> documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

And check if your user is in the list. If it's in the list that means it is an administrator.

Here's an example of the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
{
  "value": [
    {
      "businessPhones":["000-000-0000"],
      "displayName":"Adele Vance",
      "givenName":"Adele",
      "jobTitle":null,
      "mail":"AdeleV@contoso.com",
      "officeLocation":null,
      "preferredLanguage":"en-US",
      "surname":"Vance",
      "userPrincipalName":"AdeleV@contoso.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the above solution worked for me with a slight change in the second Graph API `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/roleTemplateId=62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10/members`

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "Admin" you mean Team "Owner". If so, on the context object there is a `userTeamRole` property which will contain `Owner`, `user`, or `guest`. See more at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.userteamrole?view=msteams-client-js-latest

Comment: No, I am looking for the admin of the tenant.